# jQuery remove fade and just have show?

Tags: jquery

How would I remove the fadeIn/Fadeout from this and just have a show? e.g. I just want to pull the ajax content right in without any effects...or gimmicks into the div... #mc_calendar.

My code:

```
function buildCal (responseHTML){
// where are we going to put our AJAX calendar?
var target = jQuery('#mc_calendar');

//how fast do we want it to fade out?
target.fadeOut(100, function(){
    target.empty();
    target.html(responseHTML)

    // how fast do we want it to fade in?
    target.fadeIn(50);
    initMonthLinks(target)
});
}
```

Comment: You can change the duration to `0`, or replace `fadeIn/fadeOut` with `show/hide`.

Comment: Honestly, this may be the most poorly researched question I have ever seen.

Comment: Did you even bother to try replacing `.fadeIn()` with `.show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a fan of one-line solutions:

```
initMonthLinks(target.hide().html(responseHTML).show());
```

However, hiding and showing doesn't make any sense here. If `target` is always visible use just:

```
initMonthLinks(target.html(responseHTML));
```

Comment: Exactly, i'm not trying to hide anything, just fill a div...sorry where do i put your code in context with my example?

Comment: @CodeyMonkey After `var target = jQuery('#mc_calendar');` instead of `target.fadeOut ...` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildCal (responseHTML){
    // where are we going to put our AJAX calendar?
    var target = jQuery('#mc_calendar');
    target.html(responseHTML);
    initMonthLinks(target);
});
```